# How can I obtain a value from an output parameter while also providing a value as an input?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using my code in C# below

```
 cn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Get_Cur", cn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("@cur", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                parm.Size = 3;
                parm.Value = s_cur;
                parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);

                SqlParameter parm2 = new SqlParameter("@val", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                parm2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                parm2.Value = val;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parm2);

                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();

                return (decimal)cmd.Parameters["@val"].Value; 
            }
```

my SP is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_Get_Cur
@cur VARCHAR(3),
@val decimal(16,2) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @rate decimal(16,2)
    SELECT @rate = rate FROM exchange_rate WHERE code = @cur

    SET @val =   @val / @rate

END
```

But I am getting the error: {"Specified cast is not valid."}

I wanted to get the result of a currency from my exchange rate table.

Is there a better way of getting results simplier than doing output parameter direction type?

TEST RESULTS in SQL:

```
DECLARE @val decimal(16,2)
SET @val = 5
EXECUTE sp_Get_Cur 'EUR', @val output
SELECT @val

Result =    6.76
```

in Code Watch, my cmd.Parameters["@val"].Value;  = 5.00;

when executed it becomes {} or null?

Comment: What is the data type for the rate column on your exchange rate table?

Comment: the same, decimal(16,2).

Comment: It seems I am not getting any results from my Output parameter, even tho I tested it in SQL Query first.

Comment: Maybe I'm dumb, but I see `@val` not initialized to anything in your procedure before dividing itself by `@rate`. I quickly tested that in SQL Server and produced a null output. Check and see if the `.Value` of your result in code happens to equal `DBNull.Value`, but really, it appears you have a bug in your stored procedure you need to correct first.

Comment: It is one of the parameters, cur and val. Cant you use output variables?

Comment: Ah, well, I'll admit to not using output parameters, so passing *in* a value to an output parameter is also something I haven't done. If the documentation suggests that works (you have checked the documentation, correct?), then forget anything I've said. Unless `val` is null in your code, then remember it.

Comment: I have added my test results in SQL and the Code Watch

Comment: I used this: public decimal get_curr(string s_cur, decimal val)

Comment: it seems the problem is in SQL, when I set the value of the Stored Procedure in the last line of code to: SET @val = 1. It returns 1 properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify the parameter as output only it will not pass any value into the stored procedure, hence inside the procedure you will be dividing with a null which returns a null.

Change the parameter direction like this:

```
parm2.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
```